# Programmatically defining `redim.range` in Holoviews

Tags: python-3.x, holoviews

I want to be able to programmatically change the range of a DynamicMap based on a variable name for the kdim. For example:

```
frequencies = [0.5, 0.75, 1.0, 1.25]

def sine_curve(phase, freq):
    xvals = [0.1* i for i in range(100)]
    return hv.Curve((xvals, [np.sin(phase+freq*x) for x in xvals]))

dmap = hv.DynamicMap(sine_curve, kdims=['phase', 'frequency'])
dmap.redim.range(phase=(0.5,1)).redim.range(frequency=(0.5,1.25))
```

I want to do something like this:

```
label = 'frequency'
dmap = hv.DynamicMap(sine_curve, kdims=['phase', label])
dmap.redim.range(phase=(0.5,1)).redim.range(label=(0.5,1.25))
```

Is there a proper way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To programmatically define keyword arguments in Python you can simply create a dictionary and unpack it, e.g. in your example that would look like this:

```
dmap.redim.range(**{'phase': (0.5, 1), label: (0.5, 1.25)})
```